# Push XML data directly to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

ELEMENTS` will return SQL data directly as XML , is there is a proper way of pushing a XML file directly to SQL server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to import xml files into a database then I would use `BULK INSERT` or `OPENROWSET(BULK 'filename', SINGLE_BLOB)` (ref:[BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx)):

```
DECLARE @BulkImport TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    X XML
);

INSERT  @BulkImport (X)
SELECT  a.b
FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK N'd:\src.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS a(b);

SELECT  *
FROM    @BulkImport;
```

Results:

```
ID          X
----------- -----------------------------
1           <row PurchaseOrderID="10" ...
```

Comment: Note: SQL Server must have access to file's location.